# how to convert blade file into pdf and image in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i want to make a blade file in my laravel and then export it as png or pdf file to my users as a certificate for their exam . now i know that for pdf there is a package called `laravel/dumpdf` but i want to know if there is any package for laravel to do the same thing but for the png or any image type . thanks in advance .
this is how i am doing it with the mattewexcel and i want to know if i can to this with this package to just to convert to image .

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Exports\UsersExport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

class UsersController extends Controller 
{
    public function export() 
    {
        return Excel::download(new UsersExport, 'users.xlsx');
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/spatie/browsershot

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi thanks for the package but i am not sure if i can send my custom data per user to this package and save it in user history for later downloads .

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi I'm not sure if it's possible. your best bet would be to send back that html certificate design code. and use browser to do that job. Browsershot is perfect tool for you